# posting object spring restcontroller?

Tags: jquery, json, spring, rest, post

I can't get this thing to work. The project works perfectly aside from when I try to post an actual object. I can post single strings just fine.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>post test</h1>
    <button id="postButton">post</button>
    <script>
        var myObject = {
            name : "Johnny",
            field : "something"
        };
        $(function() {
            $("#postButton").click(function() {
                $.post("posting", JSON.stringify(myObject), function(data, status) {
                    alert(status);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
package app.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import model.MyObject;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/posting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void posting(@RequestBody MyObject myObject) {
        System.out.println(myObject.getName());
    }

}
```

myObject:

```
package model;

public class MyObject {

    private String name;

    private String field;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried it without the JSON.stringify and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

What status are you getting back? My first thought is you're probably getting an `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type` because you're probably not sending `Content-Type: application/json` to your controller.

Whatever error message you're getting would probably help answer.